# PostgreSQL to H2 engine: Data source setup issues

Tags: postgresql, odbc, h2

I'm attempting to configure a data source for a postgreSQL ODBC driver through the ODBC Data Source Administrator tool (the 64-bit version, located under Windows/System32), pointing to an H2 database server as a source. I'm following the instructions provided [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/Z6gE1VaUf6o) and [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#odbc_driver).

I am getting a connection, but then the following error is reported:

> server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

Settings are as follows:

- **Data Source:** H2
- **Description:** H2
- **Database:** jdbc:h2:tcp:\localhost\~\Desktop\H2 testing\TESTING_LifeLoop\test;ifexists=true
- **SSL mode:** disable
- **Server:** localhost
- **Port:** 5435
- **User Name:** sa
- **Password:** (same as for the H2 console)

I'm not 100% certain the password is correct, and entering other passwords (including what I believe to be the default for H2 servers, "sa"), returns the same error. The database server is accessible through the H2 console using the password I have entered here, so I can only assume the password required to set up the pSQL ODBC data source would be the same.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if you have a running process on the port you are trying to connect to.

What worked for me, was to shorten JDBC URL, deleting the beginning. Try to remain only name (test, in your case).

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer (shortening the URL) , worked like a charm!